# javascript intertwined creating element

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create something like this in javascript,

```
<li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between">
                    Todo 1
                    <a href="#" class="delete-item">
                        <i id="a" class="fa fa-remove"></i>
                    </a>

                </li>
```

but when ı create, *li* and *a* tags not intertwined.separately
code here;

```
const listItem = document.createElement('li')
const link = document.createElement('a')
link.href = '#'
link.className = 'delete-item'
link.innerHTML = '<i id="a" class="fa fa-remove"></i>'
listItem.className = 'list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between'
listItem.appendChild(document.createTextNode(newTodo))
listItem.appendChild(link)

todoList.appendChild(listItem)

console.log(listItem)
```

so what should ı do

Comment: `document.createTextNode(newTodo)` what's that?

Comment: Besides the line above I mentioned, the script you provided works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

This may be easier for you:

```
var markup = "<li class='list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between'>Todo 1<a href="#" class='delete-item'><i id='a' class='fa fa-remove'></i></a></li>";

todoList.html(markup).show();
```